# How do I fetch existing data from Firebase Database?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve a Real Time Database in the Firebase. I want my app to fetch them and display in the app. How do I do it? The app is based on AngularJS platform with HTML & CSS as front-end.

Data to fetch from the database:

[image: 1]

Firebase Project script:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for changes from Firebase and then update your angular model.
there is quick example,

```
myApp.controller('UserController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // get status of user after login
    $scope.userStatus = window.User.status;

    var userStatus = firebase.database().ref('users/' + id + '/status');
    //update user status from firebase
    userStatus.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      $scope.userStatus = snapshot.val();
    });
}]);

<div ng-controller="UserController">
    Account Status: {{ userStatus }}
</div>
```